# How to store Multidimensional data in an ArrayList

Tags: string, arraylist, multidimensional-array, store

> ArrayList group = new ArrayList();
>
> group.add("John Smith","5126123");

I would like to store 2 datas. So I can acces the name by the number and the number by the name. Is this possible with ArrayList and how?

*And different people can have the same groupnumber

Comment: You question is a bit obsolete. Are your name and number always unique ? Or is only the number OR name unique? If your number OR name is unique you should use a Map instead of an ArrayList. Otherwise you have to start using an ArrayList inside an ArrayList so it is 2dimensional.

Comment: Let me write an example:
group.add("John Smith","1");
group.add("Elis Smith","1");
group.add("Michael Smith","1");
group.add("Luuk Daves","2");

Comment: You could make a HashMap where the number is the key, and store the names that belong to that key into an ArrayList, so you will have a HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>. But then you will have to iterate over your hash map to search for the name in the ArrayList.

Comment: Or if you want to work more OO then you could make a 'User' bean with a name and id attribute, instantiate it with the user details, and add that bean to an ArrayList. Then overwrite your 'equals' method to fulfil your search needs.

Comment: I need to acces the name by asking with the number, and otherwise. Hashmap is key/value, so that's not really going to work. Name has to be unique and the number not.

I gues iterate over the Hashmap is the best solution.

Comment: I posted a simple solution, which will work OK if you don't have a lot of data. But if you want to traverse search trough lots of data (thousands and more) you might want to use a framework like Lucene for search indexing etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ArrayList in this way:-

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
                Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map1.put("John Smith","5126123");
                         list.add(map1);
```

Or You Can use Map Directly:-

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
map.put("Some String", 42);
// or, more correctly:
map.put("Some String", Integer.valueOf(42));
```

You can search it using

```
Integer result = map.get("Some String");
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution (but maybe not the most effective):
This is not typed in an IDE so there may be typo's in here.

public class User {

```
private int id;
private String name;

public User() {};

public User(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

}

public class MyUserArray() {

```
private ArrayList<User> users;

public MyUserArray() {
    users = new ArrayList<User>();
}

public add() {
    users.add(user);
}

// Since you said the user name is unique, only
// one user will be returned
public User getUserByName(String name) {
    for(User user : users) {
        if(user.getName().equalsIgoreCase(name)) 
            return user;
    }

    // return null if no user is found
    return null;
}

// Since more users can have the same id, we will
// return an array list with results
public ArrayList<User> getUsersById(int id) {

    ArrayList<User> result = new ArrayList<User>();

    for(User user : users) {
        if(user.getId() == id) 
            result.add(user);
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

public class MyClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create users
    User user1 = new User(1, "John Doe");
    User user2 = new User(1, "Jack Sparrow");
    User user3 = new User(2, "Mickey Mouse");

    // Create the personal user array
    MyUserArray users = new MyUserArray();

    // Add the users
    users.add(user1);
    users.add(user2);
    users.add(user3);

    // Now you can search on id:
    ArrayList<User> userArrayList = users.getUsersById(1);
    for (User user : userArrayList) {
        System.out.println(user.getId() + " - " + user.getName());
        // This will print:
        // 1 - John Doe
        // 1 - Jack Sparrow
    }

    // Or search on name
    User user = users.getUserByName("Jack Sparrow");
    System.out.println(user.getId() + " - " + user.getName());
    // This will print: 1 - Jack Sparrow
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could store an array inside an array list like so
`group.add(new String[][] {"John Smith", "5125123"});`

However, I'm not sure how useful that'd be in helping you accomplish whatever you want to accomplish.

An alternative would be using a hash table or some other implementation of a map/dictionary data type that takes in `<key, value>` pairs. However, searching would be limited to using the key only.

Another alternative would be to create an object to hold John Smith and his associated info, and then put that object in the arraylist instead. You'd have to write some additional code to help you search and retrieve your data though.

Comment: How can I accomplish that?

  ArrayList<String> group = new ArrayList<String>();
  group.add(new String[][] {"John Smith", "5125123"});

and should 
group.get("John Smith") -> 5125123
group.get("5125123") -> John Smith (And the other members of the group)